# Create a PDF file using PDFTron and then rename or delete it

Tags: pdf, uwp, pdftron

I am trying to create PDF file using PDFTron in application which runs in the UWP environment. I am able to create a file successfully. Depending on user input that newly created file might need to be renamed or completely deleted from the system. Although when I try to access the file that was just created the system throws the following exception:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.IO.IOException' in System.IO.FileSystem.dll The process cannot access the file (filename) because it is being used by another process.
```

The following part show what is used for the file to be created:

```
await sdfDoc.SaveAsync(filePath, SDFDocSaveOptions.e_linearized, "%PDF-1.5");  
sdfDoc.Dispose();
```

And this is my delete implementation:

```
var filedelete = Task.Run(() => File.Delete(filePath));
```

The creation of the file is running on a seperate Task and the deletion takes place upon a button press.

I understand the nature of the exception, although I was wondering if the resources of the file are returned to the system from PDFTron after the creation of the file?

Any help or direction would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: 1) Can you show how you instantiate the PDFDoc object. Do you pass in a StorageFile? 2) What filetype is filePath in your call to SaveAsync? 3) Is the PDFDoc object being passed to PDFViewCtrl for viewing? 4) Why is renaming/deleting a file being accessed important for you?

Comment: Thank you for the response Ryan: 1)For instantiation I use - PDFDoc pdfdoc = new PDFDoc(); and SDFDoc sdfDoc = pdfdoc.GetSDFDoc(); 2) I do not use a storage file to access the file, only the filePath which is a string pointing to the path where the file is currently saved, this string is passed to the SaveAsync as a parameter. 3) The created PDF is not passed on the PDFViewCtrl. 4) The user defines the filename of the PDF created and they might need to rename or delete in case of error.

Comment: Since you are passing in a string, is the file path inside the app's own storage? Also, can you post the output of PDFNet.GetVersion at runtime.

Comment: Indeed the filepath points inside the application's own storage (in the package folder in the LocalCache folder). In order to give you a better overview of the process, the user initially is asked to provide a name for the file to be created, the he takes photo using the camera of the device from within the app and that image file is converted to a PDF file using the SaveAsync(). In orde to create the PDF file, the filename defined by the user is used along with filePath string which points to the LocalCache folder of the app. The PDFNet.GetVersio() returned: 6.71. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

PDFNet uses reference counting internally to know when to release the filesystem handles and memory.

For example, the following would trigger the issue where the file is still locked.

```
PDFDoc doc = new PDFDoc(input_filename);
doc.InitSecurityHandler();
SDFDoc sdfdoc = doc.GetSDFDoc();
await sdfdoc.SaveAsync(output_file_path, SDFDocSaveOptions.e_linearized, "%PDF-1.5");
sdfdoc.Dispose();
await Task.Run(() => File.Delete(output_file_path)); // fails, as PDFDoc still has reference.
```

But this would work as expected.

```
using(PDFDoc doc = new PDFDoc(input_filename))
{
    doc.InitSecurityHandler();
    SDFDoc sdfdoc = doc.GetSDFDoc();
    await sdfdoc.SaveAsync(output_file_path, SDFDocSaveOptions.e_linearized, "%PDF-1.5");
    sdfdoc.Dispose();
}
await Task.Run(() => File.Delete(output_file_path)); // works
```

Note the `using` statement for the PDFDoc instance, and the manual dispose of the SDFDoc instance, though you could use a `using` statement on that also.